# Android development class organization

Tags: java, android, subclass

I am developing my first Android application. I want to organize my java source code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    }

    //more functions here


}
```

I want to be able to create sub classes in the same package to organize my code. I am just wondering if i can just extend `MainActivity` and still reference it on my main activity?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you *can* extend `MainActivity`, but it generally is a bad idea - especially if you're a beginner. 
All activities you create should derive directly from `Activity`.

Maybe **static variables** and **intent-passing** are options to you for exchanging information between activities.

Comment: how would you suggest organization my java source